# Render to texture - level of detail

Tags: python, opengl, textures

I've got a problem with my render to texture process. When I render the scene with width = height = 512 it has nearly no errors but the smaller the texture and scene gets, the more errors it gets.
The error is that regions of the texture are black, what makes no sense.

Here are some screenshots

512*512: http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/d9452fa0ba28494830fd96f0f15b9eba.png
128*128: http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/a39c141282a622f086d4a96b070a56a3.png

Here is my code how I render to texture and use the texture later

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0,0,200,0,0,-1,0,1,0)


    self.fbos = glGenFramebuffersEXT(1)
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, self.fbos)
    self.depthbuffers = (glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1)
    glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, self.depthbuffers)
    glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height)
    glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, self.depthbuffers)       

    self.textures = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.textures)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8,  width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, None);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT,  GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.textures, 0);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, self.fbos);

    glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0)
    glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE1)
    glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, (0,0,1,-1 * self.start + self.diff))       
    glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE1, (0,0,-1,self.start))   

    # render the mesh
    glTranslatef(-64,-64,-64)
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) # Enable something in OpenGL 
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY) # Enable something in OpenGL
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.vbo[1]) 
    glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,None) # Tell OpenGL that it contains only ColorValues
    #Now the vertex Buffer with positions
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,self.vbo[0]) 
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,None) # Tell OpenGL that it contains the Positions for each Points
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,len(self.verts)+len(self.color))    # Merge both

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); 
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0)
    glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0)
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0); 

    #Plane for showing texture
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)
    glClearColor(1,1,1,0)

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.textures)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
    glVertex3f(1, 1, -1)
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(1, -1, -1)
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
    glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1)
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

How can I achieve a better quality for the smaller texture? The mesh has no holes but the texture sometimes has.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to render. Is the 512^2 texture correct and you just want to make it smaller?

Comment: Exactly, but I dont want to render the 512^2 and then resize it to 128^2 I want directly to render the 128^2. Therefore I set the width and the height of my pygame surface to 128. Same for OpenGL. But then those errors occur

Comment: There are no 'errors' - it's just smaller version of the same. I think there's no magic in it - you need to make those red parts bigger, so they're visible in smaller texture. Can you show your model/materials you've used? From this pictures I can't imagine what you draw :)

Comment: Its a sphere. I've used MarchingCUbes to generate this mesh.
http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/f1a1b9fdb2b05b07dfb7114a26d23559.png    http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/f2769f254ce6c7335c881461236a0446.png     

It got a color for each vertex. 
While the rendering process I am using glClipPlane for cutting it into 128 or 512 (depending on the length) slices which I need for later calculations - the sphere has a radius of 128

Comment: Maybe if you use less slices, you'll get more geometry on single image.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still got a lot of errors... I think this happens when the vertex is parallel to the viewing direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you're expecting to see. You're drawing triangles/cubes/etc that are clearly smaller than the size of a pixel/sample size. Therefore, not all of them are going to be visible.

This is a standard aliasing problem: triangles that don't cover the center of a pixel/sample will not be visible. That's the nature of rasterization. And the only way to fix aliasing is to increase the number of samples you use. You can render at a higher resolution and downscale, or you could use MSAA or another real aliasing technique.